# Robospice Proguard Obfuscation causes for requests to "fail"

Tags: android, proguard, robospice

I am using Robospice + Spring for Android. It works fine even with Proguard shrinking the code, but when I turn on obfuscation request complete successfully (log says Notifying 1 listeners of request success      notifying null). But it seems that the listener is getting onRequestFailed instead of onRequestSuccess? Why would that be, is there something with my config file (attached below)?

```
#-optimizationpasses 5
-dontoptimize
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/commons-lang3-3.1.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/robospice-1.4.6.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/robospice-cache-1.4.6.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/robospice-spring-android-1.4.6.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
-libraryjars /Users/Ryan/git/haiku-learning-android/HaikuLearningAndroid/libs/spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar


#Specifies not to ignore non-public library classes. As of version 4.5, this is the default setting
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses

#Preverification is irrelevant for the dex compiler and the Dalvik VM, so we can switch it off with the -dontpreverify option.
-dontpreverify

#Specifies to write out some more information during processing. If the program terminates with an exception, this option will print out the entire stack trace, instead of just the exception message.


#The -optimizations option disables some arithmetic simplifications that Dalvik 1.0 and 1.5 can't handle. Note that the Dalvik VM also can't handle aggressive overloading (of static fields).
#To understand or change this check http://proguard.sourceforge.net/index.html#/manual/optimizations.html
#-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

#To repackage classes on a single package
#-repackageclasses ''

#Uncomment if using annotations to keep them.
#-keepattributes *Annotation*

#Keep classes that are referenced on the AndroidManifest
-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService


#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
}

#To avoid changing names of methods invoked on layout's onClick.
# Uncomment and add specific method names if using onClick on layouts
-keepclassmembers class * {
 public void onClickButton(android.view.View);
}

#Maintain java native methods 
-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML.
#Uncomment if having any problem with the approach below
#-keep public class custom.components.package.and.name.**

#To maintain custom components names that are used on layouts XML:
-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

#Maintain enums
-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#To keep parcelable classes (to serialize - deserialize objects to sent through Intents)
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}

#Keep the R
-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}
# For RoboSpice
#Results classes that only extend a generic should be preserved as they will be pruned by Proguard 
#as they are "empty", others are kept
-keep class com.HaikuLearning.Android.POJOs.**

#RoboSpice requests should be preserved in most cases
-keepclassmembers class com.HaikuLearning.Android.Requests.** {
  public void set*(***);
  public *** get*();
  public *** is*();
}

#Warnings to be removed. Otherwise maven plugin stops, but not dangerous
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.sun.xml.internal.**
-dontwarn com.sun.istack.internal.**
-dontwarn org.codehaus.jackson.**
-dontwarn org.springframework.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.security.**
-dontwarn java.beans.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn java.util.**
-dontwarn org.w3c.dom.**
-dontwarn com.google.common.**
-dontwarn com.octo.android.robospice.persistence.**

### Jackson SERIALIZER SETTINGS
-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* <fields>;
    @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.* <init>(...);
}
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod
 -keepnames class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
```

Comment: Have a look on https://github.com/octo-online/robospice/wiki/Proguard-configuration-for-RoboSpice-projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When obfuscation fails, you will often see warnings in the log. In eclipse select, in the logcat view, "all messages" then filter by warnings (orange).

You will see things like :

VRFY : Couldn't find class XXX or couldn't find superclass of class XXX.

You will see which classes couldn't be found, and then be able to add them to your proguard conf file.